# Mono for android - Debugging issue on Device

Tags: android, debugging, mono, xamarin.android

While trying to debug my application on real device, I ran into a problem: After a breakpoint was triggered, wait about 6 seconds (no matter I'm stepping through the code or just do nothing) the program will terminated. The Output window shows:

```
02-22 10:31:42.599 I/mono (32532): Stacktrace:
02-22 10:31:42.599 I/mono (32532):
The program 'Mono' has exited with code 255 (0xff).
```

I tried debugging on two different device (ASUS Padfone and HUAWEI C8812, both Android 4.0.4), same result.
It looks like the device terminated the program because it does not respond in a limit time. But of course it will not respond! I'm stepping through my code!

BTW debugging on emulator is fine (but SLOOOOW!! And crashes too often)

The version of my monodroid is 4.4.55, and I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with SP1 under Windows 7 (64bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the problem, here is some code, simple code, really:

```
class OwnerDrawView : View
{
    PointF m_screenPosition;

    public OwnerDrawView(Context context)
      : base(context)
    {
      this.Touch += new EventHandler<TouchEventArgs>(OwnerDrawView_Touch);
      this.SetWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
      Core.Instance.OnDraw(canvas);
      base.OnDraw(canvas);
    }

    void OwnerDrawView_Touch(object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e)
    {
      m_screenPosition = new PointF(e.Event.GetX(), e.Event.GetY());
      switch (e.Event.Action) {
        case MotionEventActions.Down:
            Core.Instance.OnTouchDown(m_screenPosition);
            break;
        case MotionEventActions.Move:
            Core.Instance.OnTouchMove(m_screenPosition);
            break;
        case MotionEventActions.Up:
            Core.Instance.OnTouchUp(m_screenPosition);
            break;
      }
    }
}
```

Don't mind the "Core" class, it's not important here (although it sounds so ^_^)
To reproduce this error, just place the breakpoint in this line:

```
Core.Instance.OnTouchDown(m_screenPosition);
```

Run the program on device, touch the screen, wait a few seconds, BOOM!
But if the breakpoint was placed on "Core.Instance.OnTouchUp(m_screenPosition)" line, then SURPRISE! Everything is fine!! What the hell!!

My entire program runs on a single thread, so it's not a multi-thread related thing. I do have a timer, but that timer only calls PostInvalidate on the "OwnerDrawView" class (Yes! I'm building a game using Canvas!)

This is probably a bug in monodroid, but if anyone out there has trouble reproducing this bug, then please ignore me (I'm always a unlucky guy....)

Comment: Please add this answer to your original question as now people think you consider the problem to be solved